# Do fingers in water get wrinkled due to a nervous system response?

Tags: physiology

I had always thought that the fingers were getting wrinkled when I left them within the water for a long time due to swelling of the outer layers of skin but I just read in several places that it is a nervous system response.

> Digit puckering was long thought to be caused by a swelling of the outer layers of skin on the fingertips and toes, but recent research showed it was actually a nervous system response to immersion in water.

- [Sydney Morning Herald, Jan 10 2013](http://www.smh.com.au/technology/sci-tech/science-gets-a-grip-on-finger-wrinkles-20130110-2chgv.html)

Is this true?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While we patiently wait for the day when journalists will learn that they should add references to original sources, here is the work they are speaking about:

[Water-induced finger wrinkles improve handling of wet objects.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23302867) - Kareklas et al., *Biol Lett.* **2013**

You can also read the press report from Newcastle University:

[Get a grip - why we get wrinkly fingers and toes](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/ion/news/news/item/get-a-grip-why-we-get-wrinkly-fingers-and-toes1)

An older study study from another group, analysed the morphology of the wrinkles, reporting that it

> has the signature properties of drainage networks, enabling efficient removal of water from the gripped surface.

[Are wet-induced wrinkled fingers primate rain treads?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21701145) - Changizi et al. , *Brain Behav Evol.* **2011**

Now, getting to your question, yes it appears to be an autonomic nervous system response, rather than a result of osmosis.
The second paper I linked has a few references regarding the fact that

> it has long been known that cuts to sympathetic innervation to a finger abolish the wrinkling response to wetness,  which has led to suggestions to use the wrinkling response as a simple test for sympathetic integrity in unresponsive patients.

Specifically, they cite this 1936 paper, which unfortunately I cannot seem to find

Circulatory changes in fingers in some diseases of the nervous system, with special reference to digital atrophy of peripheral nerve lesions. - Lewis and Pickering - *Clin Sci* **1936**

Some more recent work:

[Finger wrinkling: a test of autonomic function. Bull and Henry](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1605221/) - *Br Med J* **1977**

[Skin wrinkling for the assessment of sympathetic function in the limbs.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10696945) - Vasudevan et al. - *Aust NZ J Surg* **2000**

[Case of the month: the skin wrinkle test – a simple nerve injury test for paediatric and uncooperative patients.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2464382/) - Tindall et al. - *Emerg Med J* **2006**

Comment: Disputing the dexterity aspect: a [paper on PLOS One](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0084949). And anecdotally, but not in dispute of the involvement of the nervous system, I have observed that the likelihood of wrinkling varies with the mineral content of the water.